# Mango sappling drying out and dying

Tags: mango

I am from India, and the average temperature where I live ranges from 30° C - 42° C ( 85°F - 105° F).
I grew this mango plant from seed and it was growing really healthy and fast since the last two months, but recently for about a week or so, it started wilting and yellowing. I assumed this happened because I did not allow too much of sunlight to fall on it as I suspected it would immediately kill the plant in the arid sun.

I later started putting in the sun, but it did not help, instead started getting worse.

I water it properly, and soil fertility does not seem the problem as my other plants in the same soil are healthy.

[image: mango]

Does the soil look too clayey? Is this a disease or malnutrition?

[image]